# how to handle whitespace in input array of expression parsing

Tags: python, algorithm

i'm making expression parsing algorithm using stack by python and when i input equation without whitespaces like this "1+2*3+10" it doesn't work properly,sometimes give error result and sometimes it give an error , it should be entered like "1 + 2 * 3 + 10" to work

```
def applyOp(a, b, op):   
    if op == '+': return a + b 
    if op == '-': return a - b 
    if op == '*': return a * b 
    if op == '/': return a // b 

def evaluate(tokens): 
    values = Stack() 
    ops = Stack() 
    i = 0
    while i < len(tokens): 
        if tokens[i] == ' ': 
            i += 1
            continue
        elif tokens[i] == '(': 
            ops.push(tokens[i]) 
        elif tokens[i].isdigit(): 
            val = 0
            while (i < len(tokens) and
                tokens[i].isdigit()): 
                val = (val * 10) + int(tokens[i]) 
                i += 1
            values.push(val) 
        elif tokens[i] == ')': 
            while ops.peek() != None and ops.peek() != '(': 
                val2 = values.pop() 
                val1 = values.pop() 
                op = ops.pop() 
        # print(val2 , val1 , op)
                values.push(applyOp(val1, val2, op)) 
            ops.pop()
        else:
            while (ops.peek() != None and
                precedence(ops.peek()) >= precedence(tokens[i])):                          
                val2 = values.pop() 
                val1 = values.pop() 
                op = ops.pop() 
                values.push(applyOp(val1, val2, op)) 
            ops.push(tokens[i]) 
        i += 1
    while ops.peek() != None: 
        val2 = values.pop() 
        val1 = values.pop() 
        op = ops.pop() 
        values.push(applyOp(val1, val2, op)) 
    return values.peek()
```

Comment: How do you input the values? I cannot see it on your code.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work properly" mean? Is there an error message, does it give the wrong output, is it an infinite loop, or something else? Please see [ask].

Comment: I think it would be advisable to use a compiler-compiler (a parser generator). You then thus write the grammar, and let the compiler-compiler do the work.

Comment: @kaya3 i made edit on my post

Comment: Your edit added none of the required information. What error message, what incorrect results, and for what inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but

```
elif tokens[i].isdigit(): 
        val = 0
        while (i < len(tokens) and
            tokens[i].isdigit()): 
            val = (val * 10) + int(tokens[i]) 
            i += 1
        values.push(val)
```

advances `i` too far. It stops when `i` is already pointing to something that's not a digit, and then when you advance `i` again at the end of the outer while loop you will miss whatever was there, which doesn't matter if it's a space - so that's why spaces fix it.

EDIT: Okay so I tried it out, swapping the mentioned `elif` statement with this should work:

```
elif tokens[i].isdigit():
    val = int(tokens[i])
    while i+1 < len(tokens) and tokens[i+1].isdigit():
        i += 1
        val = (val * 10) + int(tokens[i])
    values.append(val)
```